# DBX Join two database together and filter out the result

Tags: join, splunk, dbx

I can write a search like this:

```
| dbquery "DB1" "SELECT A.* AOS.* FROM Assets A JOIN AssetOSs AOS ON A.AssetOSID = AOS.AssetOSID" | append [ dbquery "DB2" "SELECT DB1A.IPAddressStr DB2M.User FROM DB1.Assets DB1A JOIN DB2.Machines DB2M ON DB1A.IPAddressStr = DB2M.IP"
```

The above query combines the result of DB1 with DB2

But how would I do a dbquery to exclude the result of DB2 from DB1 result

For Example :

DB1 Result : A,B,C,D
DB2 Result :  C,D

Since C and D are present DB2 result  i want to exclde them in DB1 Result and get only A, B in the final result

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested query.

```
| dbquery "DB1" "SELECT A.* AOS.* FROM Assets A JOIN AssetOSs AOS ON A.AssetOSID = AOS.AssetOSID" 
| search NOT [ dbquery "DB2" "SELECT DB1A.IPAddressStr DB2M.User FROM DB1.Assets DB1A JOIN DB2.Machines DB2M ON DB1A.IPAddressStr = DB2M.IP"]
```